# $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and decreasing on $(a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

If a function $f$ is defined and continuous on $[a,b]$ also is decreasing on $(a,b]$ would that necessarily mean it takes its greatest value at $a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. You could show this in the following way:

Let $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be any decreasing sequence in $(a,b]$ with $x_n \rightarrow a$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Then as $f$ is decreasing on $(a,b]$ it must be the case that $(f(x_n))_{n \geq 1}$ is increasing. By continuity of $f$ we have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(a)$, but since $(f(x_n))_{n \geq 1}$ is increasing we have $f(a) \geq f(x_n)$ for every term $x_n$ in the sequence. Since the sequence was arbitrary this implies that $f(a) \geq f(x)$ for every $x \in (a,b]$.